# Zend Framework Class 'Table' not found error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

I have basic zend framework installation. I create new db table models/tables/User.php

```
<?php 

require_once 'Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php';

class UserTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'user';
}
```

And later in IndexController I make a call to table:

```
public function indexAction()
{

        $userTable = new UserTable();
}
```

But I get fatal error: Fatal error: Class 'UserTable' not found. What I do wrong ?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of the file?

Comment: _What I do wrong ?_ You didn't start with the documentation. http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html would be a really good place to start. http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/ is also really good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the naming. In Zend the classes are autoloaded according to its name.

If the name of the file is **User.php**, the class name should be **User**
If the file is in the location **Models/Usertable.php** the class name should be **Models_Usertable**

There are several methods of autoloading techniques in ZF. Check this manual [learning.autoloading.design](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.autoloading.design.html#learning.autoloading.design.naming)